# Word split fails with more then 3 words

Tags: vb.net, string-function

I try to split a string every `+` then every `|`, it works fine when I try to read only 3 words from the split `words1(0-3)`, but when I try to read `words1(4)` the whole function fails... here is the code:

```
Private Function SetUpdateData()
    Try
        Dim delimiterChars As Char() = {"+"c}
        Dim words As String() = updatelist.Split(delimiterChars)

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i < words.Length)
            Dim delimiterChars1 As Char() = {"|"c}
            Dim words1 As String() = words(i).Split(delimiterChars1)

            Dim name As String = words1(0)
            Dim version As String = words1(1)
            Dim fileurl As String = words1(2)
            Dim size As String = (words1(3) / 1024D / 1024D).ToString("0.00") & " MB"

            Dim cversion As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" & name))
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" & name) Then
                If Not version.Contains(cversion.FileVersion) Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, version, size)
                    RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3))
                End If
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, version, size)
                RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3))
            End If
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try
End Function
```

This above works no problem at all, but when you add `words1(4)` in like this:

```
Private Function SetUpdateData()
    Try
        Dim delimiterChars As Char() = {"+"c}
        Dim words As String() = updatelist.Split(delimiterChars)

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i < words.Length)
            Dim delimiterChars1 As Char() = {"|"c}
            Dim words1 As String() = words(i).Split(delimiterChars1)

            Dim name As String = words1(0)
            Dim version As String = words1(1)
            Dim fileurl As String = words1(2)
            Dim size As String = (words1(3) / 1024D / 1024D).ToString("0.00") & " MB"
            Dim status As String = words1(4)

            Dim cversion As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" & name))
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\" & name) Then
                If Not version.Contains(cversion.FileVersion) Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, version, size)
                    RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3) & "|" & words(4))
                End If
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(name, version, size)
                RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3) & "|" & words(4))
            End If
            i = (i + 1)
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("error")
    End Try
End Function
```

ALSO the string that it is splitting is:

```
+Thing v2.exe|1.0.0.1|http://example.com/uploads/Thing v2.exe|205824|Primary+Thing v2 DLL.dll|1.0.0.1|http://example.com/uploads/Thing DLL.dll|1097728|Secondary
```

Which all should output:

```
words1(0) - Thing v2.exe 
words1(1) - 1.0.0.1 
words1(2) - http://example.com/uploads/Thing v2.exe 
words1(3) - 205824 
words1(4) - Primary
```

But as I said above once words1(4) is used it crashes the whole function...

It will catch and fail and give the error message, but when I try to do `msgbox(ex)` for the exception error, no `msgbox` pops up and the program just continues.

If anyone can fix the issue or give me some help that would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance and sorry if this is confusing as it is to me too!

Comment: @Vivek.S It's supposed to output:
`words1(0) - Thing v2.exe`
`words1(1) - 1.0.0.1`
`words1(2) - http://example.com/uploads/Thing v2.exe`
`words1(3) - 205824`
`words1(4) - Primary`

Comment: Are you trying to split by either `|` or `+`? The overload of [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you are using can be used like this: `updatelist.Split({"+"c,"|"c})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two loops in your program:
Loop1: 
words1(0)>>Thing v2.exe

words1(1)>>1.0.0.1

words1(2)>>http://example.com/uploads/Thing v2.exe

words1(3)>>205824

words1(4)>>Primary

Loop2:
words1(0)>>Thing v2 DLL.dll

words1(1)>>1.0.0.1

words1(2)>>http://example.com/uploads/Thing DLL.dll

words1(3)>>1097728

words1(4)>>Secondary

it appears that you misspelled your words1(4) to words(4) in below line

```
 RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3) & "|" & words(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your split functionality works fine but there's an error on the following lines (there are 2 of them):

```
RichTextBox1.AppendText("+" & words1(0) & "|" & words1(1) & "|" & words1(2) & "|" & words1(3) & "|" & words(4))
```

The last `words(4)` should be `words1(4)`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what it was!